# Get a specific product in a cart page

Tags: php, magento, cart

Is there any way to display a specific product custom options (Check Box) to displayd in a cart page by modifying `/frontend/custom/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml` without having to create a custom module from the scratch? I have tried below method but it displays only options name not radio input.

```
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(1); //product id 1
$i = 1;
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
    echo "<strong>Custom Option:" . $i . "</strong><br/>";
    echo "Custom Option TITLE: " . $o->getTitle() . "<br/>"; //Colors
    echo "Custom Option TYPE: " . $o->getType() . "<br/>"; //drop_down
    echo "Custom Option Values: <br/>";
    $values = $o->getValues();
    foreach ($values as $v) {
        print_r($v->getData());
    }
    $i++;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

**Update 1:** I did manage to get the checkbox option name but the actual checkbox is not showing up. I would like to display checkbox name and checkbox input as well where a customer should be able to check

```
<?php 
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(227);
    $i = 1;
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
        echo "Custom Option TITLE: " . $o->getTitle() . "<br/>";
        $values = $o->getValues();
        $i++;
        echo "<br/>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: What's not working? Couldn't load the product, couldn't get the options, couldn't get the option values?

Comment: Please clarify the question..

Comment: I did manage the make the code work but it is displaying only custom option name not check box. Is there any way to display checkbox as well and while selecting the checkbox the cart should get updated?

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you look into it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put if under foreach 
    if($o->getType() == "checkbox")
     {
      //your code here
     }

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you look into it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
$product=M age::getModel( "catalog/product")->load(227);
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o):?> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="your_name" value="<?php echo $o->getTitle() ?>"><?php echo $options->getTitle()?>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it is showing empty page. Note: I am trying to add this custom option in a Magento cart page.

Comment: Are you sure that this product has custom options?

Comment: yes, it does have custom options. I have updated my question and if you look at the code at **Update 1** section, the code displays name of the custom option.

Comment: It should work, i have try my code. Maybe you are put this code not in correct place.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I did tried your code and it is showing up a single checkbox. The product is having two custom options and the other issue is that wherever I add the code it breaks rest of the display after the checkbox.

Comment: Please see your php errors. Correct them and all custom option will be displayed.

Comment: Or, you can add your file here, i will check.